# Unable to update stored procedure in to 3 tier architecture in code first

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, ssms, 3-tier

I have an existing project which is developed into 3-tier architecture pattern. It has BLL and DAL .dll files in reference.

Now I want to access a new Stored procedure which already created in ssms to use in this project.
I create a method in to .cs file having Stored Procedure Name and Parameters of BLL. build the code and then tried to fetch the particular method from controller but controller didn't fetch the method which i developed in to .cs file.

- MetaData File :-

  public int AddChapter(string dOCTitleID, string topicalTitleId, string partTitleId, string chapterNumber, string chapterTitles, string parentChapterId);
- Method Created in Chapter.cs file :

  ```
  public int AddChapterSelect(int dOCTitleID, int topicalTitleId, int partTitleId, string chapterNumber, string chapterTitles, int subChapterId)
  {
       return dam.ExecuteDataSetByUpdate("USP_AddChapter", dOCTitleID, topicalTitleId, partTitleId, chapterNumber, chapterTitles, subChapterId);

  }
  ```

  Stored Procedure

  ```
  ALTER PROC [dbo].[USP_AddChapter]        
  (        
  @DOCTitleID int,        
  @TopicalTitleID int,        
  @PartTitleID int,        
  @ChapterNumber nvarchar(50),        
  @ChapterTitles nvarchar(max),        
  @SubChapterID int      
  )        
  as        
  begin            
       insert into Chapters(DOCTitleID,TopicalTitleID,PartTitleID,ChapterNumber,ChapterTitles,SubChapterID)        
   values(nullif(@DOCTitleID,0),nullif(@TopicalTitleID,0),nullif(@PartTitleID,0),@ChapterNumber,@ChapterTitles,nullif(@SubChapterID,0))            
  end
  ```

Please help out that, how can i update the SP in db and access to my Controller.

Comment: controller didn't fetch that particular method?? How's your code building then if your method doesn't exist. If here you are talking about the SP, then elaborate on the error you are facing

Comment: Sir,
Here situation is -
1. The already developed SP working fine and also fetch from Method into Controller.
2. But when I create a new SP i didn't find it.

Comment: please add 4 spaces before every line of code. It will be more readable.

Comment: Sure Sir, I will do .

Comment: what do mean by didn't fetch the method? Is it throwing any error?

Comment: "class_A" doesn't contain a definition for "method_B" and o extension method "method_B" accepting a first argument of type could be found.

Comment: do you mean to say "ExecuteDataSetByUpdate" when you say "method_B"

Comment: Method B is 
AddChapterSelect()

Comment: where are you calling the method? add that code also. and check if you have added the references at the top of the cs file. You have to add `using <namespace>` to the cs file to use the methods.

Comment: In to the controller of demo.aspx.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

I just directly call the stored procedure from controller and add the namespace of existing DAL which have implemented DataAccessMethod.

Create a object of DataAccessMethod.

**Steps here -**

- Add namespace -

  ```
                     using DAL;
  ```
- Create Object of DAL's Data Access Method

  ```
           DataAccessMethod dm = new DataAccessMethod();
  ```
- Create a method for calling Stored Procedure

  `public int AddChapterSelect(string subchapterNumber, string subchapterTitles, string chapterId)
      {
          return dm.ExecuteDataSetByUpdate("USP_AddChapterSelect", subchapterNumber, subchapterTitles, chapterId);
      }`
- Called it in to My Function :

  `protected void btnAddChapter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          if (ddlSelectDocumentTitle.SelectedItem.Value != "0")
          {
              int res = AddChapterSelect(txtSubChapterNumber.Text, txtSubChapterTitle.Text, ddlChapter_Popup.SelectedValue);
              if (res > 0)
              {
                  lblSelectMsg.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                  lblSelectMsg.Text = "Record saved successfully";
                  txtChapterNumber.Text = "";
                  txtChapterTitle.Text = "";
                  txtSubChapterNumber.Text = "";
                  txtSubChapterTitle.Text = "";
                  Bind_ddlChapter();
              }
          }
          else
          {
              lblSelectMsg.ForeColor = Color.Green;
              lblSelectMsg.Text = "Please select document title";
          }
      }`

Thanks :)